# Python selenium with PhantomJS cannot find element on Ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, phantomjs

I'm working on a Django project on my local computer, which is OSX. I want to deploy my site to an Ubuntu server, but I ran into a problem. The same piece of code that runs without a hitch on my local computer does not work on the Ubuntu server. This is the piece of code:

```
browser.get("https://degreeworks.cuny.edu/cuny_redirector.cgi")
browser.switch_to_frame('frBody')
try:
    step[clientId] = "Loading your Degree Audit"
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'SchoolName')))
except:
    browser.quit()
    return {'error': 'could not load DegreeWorks'}
```

On OSX Selenium eventually finds the element with class 'SchoolName' and continues the function. On Ubuntu the same exact version of Selenium (3.0.2) and the same version of PhantomJS (2.1.1) cannot find that element.

I printed the `browser.page_source` on both and the results were interestingly different.
Both had the same html source while the AJAX page was loading.
But then, once AJAX loaded the XML for the page, on OSX it outputted just

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="DGW_Report.xsl" ?>
```

whereas on Ubuntu it outputted that AND the actual XML content. I think that on OSX the XML was then translated to HTML (like it happens on the browser) and the element was found, but on Ubuntu it just kept printing the XML.

Does anybody know why this is happening and if there's a way to fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Just a little update. I reinstalled PhantomJS version 1.9.8 and had the same problem. I reinstalled everything on Ubuntu 64-bit and had the same problem. Installing Chrome and using the Chrome webdriver instead of PhantomJS worked :(